# Difference between ObjectMapper().createObjectNode vs. JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503604/how-to-create-insert-new-nodes-in-jsonnode) about inserting new nodes to `JsonNode` and encountered two separate answers, but I can't grasp the difference between the two.

From my little experience, `ObjectMapper` doesn't allow you to create anything but `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode` while `JsonNodeFactory` allows you to create [a whole bunch of nodes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ContainerNode.html).

Apart from that, what are other differences?

Also, given that `ObjectMapper` is [considered expensive](https://theartofdev.com/2014/07/20/jackson-objectmapper-performance-pitfall/), I was wondering if the latter way is more efficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no difference between the following approaches:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
```

```java
ObjectNode objectNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
```

Under the hood, Jackson will delegate the [`createObjectNode()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#createObjectNode()) method to [`JsonNodeFactory`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory.html).

For more details on how to use [`JsonNodeFactory`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory.html), refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319491/1426227).

Comment: So if all I want from `ObjectMapper` is create `ObjectNode`, will it be more efficient if I use `JsonNodeFactory` instead since it won't have to create `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP If you just need to create `ObjectNode` instances, the `JsonNodeFactory` is enough for you.

Comment: Just to make sure, even if I am making multiple `ObjectNodes` through `JsonNodeFactory`, it should be cheaper than creating a new `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP I haven't done any performance tests, but if you have a look at the `ObjectMapper` default constructor, you'll realize that a lot of objects are being created. For sure it will consume more resources than just using the `JsonNodeFactory`. If you just need to create `ObjectNode` instances and don't need to perform any mappings, use the `JsonNodeFactory`.